# android webview onPageFinished redirect to new page from JavascriptInterface?

Tags: android, webview

got a webview loading a page on finished the javascript function getting called

but when i try to browser.loadUrl to new page this not working
how can i change the current page of webview after this loaded?

code:

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.w1);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(this, "HTMLOUT");
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });
    browser.loadUrl("page1");

@JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        if (html == null)
            return;
        browser.loadUrl("page2");    <----
```

Answer (score 0):

here are some suggestions, hope it helps

1. You should use view.loadUrl in onPageFinished
2. To avoid infinity reload page, you should check url in onPageFinished
3. Following is a rough sample (without loading javascript), sometimes onPageFinished may need time to load, just wait for a second

   ```
    WebView browser = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(!url.contains("google")){
                Log.i("test", "onPageFinished, reload another");
                view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            }
        }
    });
    browser.loadUrl("https://www.yahoo.com");
   ```